# why i am not getting access to methods written in repository class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern

i m new to asp.net Mvc and trying to use repository-pattern with entity frame work code first approach. but now i am not getting the access in controller to the methods and code written in repository class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use dependency injection (DI) and inject the repository in the controller's constructor. Here is an example:

```
public class Controller
{
    public readonly Repository repository;

    public Controller(Repository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        this.repository.AMethodInTheRepository();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanx for replying.